# How to use increments in Python

Tags: python

```
def number():
    b = 0.1
    while True:
        yield b
        b = b + 0.1
       
b = number()
for i in range(10):
    print(next(b))
```

---

Outputs

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
0.9999999999999999
```

---

Then, I just want

```
c=b*2
print("c="=)
```

My expected outputs are

```
c=0.2
0.4
0.6
0.8
1
1.2
```

And so on.

Could you tell me what I have to do to get my expected outputs?

Comment: One possible solution is pass a number as an argument: ```def number(num):``` and then in the loop: ```b=b+num```

Comment: If you don't mind ```1.0``` instead of ```1``` as an output, you could use ```round(c, 1)```.

Comment: for i in range(10):
    c=next(b)*2
    print(c)#something like this?

Comment: You have changed the question considerably, and I don't know what you are asking any more. In general, changing the content of a question in a manner that invalidates existing answers (as opposed to clarifying the question) should not be done; you should have asked a new question instead.

Comment: @Amadan: I've rolled the question back to the original content (modulo minor edits made by others to improve spelling/formatting). As you say, the OP should ask a new question rather than invalidating existing answers by asking a new (and to my mind, less clear on the problem) question through edits.

Answer (score 2):

[Floating point numbers are not precise.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) The more you handle them, the more error they can accumulate. To have numbers you want, the best way is to keep things integral for as long as possible:

```
def number():
    b = 1
    while True:
        yield b / 10.0
        b += 1
```

Comment: Could you again check my post? I have made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the number as an argument:

```
def number(start=0.1,num=0.1):
    b = start
    while True:
        yield round(b,1)
        b += num
       
b = number(0,0.2)
```

It yields:

```
0
0.2
0.4
0.6
0.8
1.0
1.2
1.4
1.6
1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
for i in range(10):
    AnotherB=next(b)
    c=AnotherB*2

    print(AnotherB)
    print("c="+str(c))
```

or do you mean how do you reset a yeild?
just redeclare it.

```
def number():
    b = 0.1
    while True:
        yield round(b,1)
        b = b + 0.1
       
b = number()
for i in range(10):
    print(next(b))
    
b=number()
for i in range(10):
    print("c="+str(next(b)*2))
```

Comment: Could you again check my post. If it is possible.